# MySQL normalizing points with latitude > 90

Tags: mysql-spatial

Facing very strange problem, I've points table for storing location of users in location(POINT) column. Problem with `st_distance_sphere` function where I've stored some specific location.

```
update points set location = point(30.492039, 76.587216) WHERE id = 1;
```

its Working fine but when I've changed lat,lng to

```
update points set location = point(52.051503, 113.471190) WHERE id = 1;
```

its called:

```
Incorrect arguments to st_distance_sphere
```

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `points` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) ,
  `location` point,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

**Query:**

```
    SELECT id,ST_Distance_Sphere(point(52.408089, 113.489844),location)/1000 
AS distance FROM points HAVING distance < 100;
```

Comment: try update points set location = point(113.471190,52.051503 ) WHERE id = 1;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the `POINT` constructor format is `POINT(longitude, latitude)`, this is, longitude first, latitude second.

MySQL wont complain if you save a point like `point(52.408089, 113.489844)` on a table field, but it won't be able to calculate distances since that point has a latitude greater than 90 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is coerce the points yourself. PostGIS does this for you,

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_MakePoint(52.408089, 113.489844)::geography);
NOTICE:  Coordinate values were coerced into range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY
         st_astext          
----------------------------
 POINT(52.408089 66.510156)
(1 row)
```

However you can do it yourself if your points are wonky, rather than

```
SELECT ST_AsText(point(-182.051503, 113.471190));
```

do this, with `%`

```
SELECT ST_AsText(point(-182.051503%180, 113.471190%90));
```